# ANDROID: Listview wont update after deleting database data

Tags: android, listview, cursor, adapter, updates

New to Android and I'm having an issue with updating my a `ListView` after deleting entries from a database.

In my activity I have a `ListView` with multiple choice `checkboxes` in each row. After the user presses a delete button, `deleteName()` gets called. `deleteName()` will then delete any Names that were checked in the `ListView`. The Names get deleted from the database, but the `ListView` never update.

I tried using `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` but nothing happens. Why wont my `ListView` update?

```
public void deleteName() {

    NamesDataSource datasource = new NamesDataSource(this);
    datasource.open();

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.namelist);
    SparseBooleanArray checked = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();

    List<Name> values = datasource.getAllNames();
    ArrayAdapter<Name> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Name>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, values);

    for (int i = 0; i < checked.size(); i++) {
        int position = checked.keyAt(i);
        if (checked.valueAt(i))
            datasource.deleteName(adapter.getItem(position));
    }

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    datasource.close();

}
```

Comment: Bad practices: 1) Finding out view everytime you delete data 2) No need to set adapter again to ListView if you use notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: try to remove the data from the values list using values.remove(location here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not optimal as you are creating a new adapter with each call to the delete method. You should maintain an activity wide reference to the adapter (possibly in your 'OnCreate')

The reason your listview is not updating is because you are filling its adapter with values but not removing the deleted ones from it.

e.g you are

```
datasource.deleteName(adapter.getItem(position));
```

but there is no corresponding

```
adapter.remove(name);
```

Comment: yes i know the code is not optimal. I left those there for reference. thanks .remove worked!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
listView.inValidate():
```

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you are adding values to `adapter` before clearing `database`

add values to `adapter` after clearing/deleting values in `database` and then call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Let me know if this helps you

Comment: Hello, thank you for explaining. so are you saying to do something like this?         adapter.add(values);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();? .add gives me errors...